# Pouchdb changes feed when hybrid app is paused

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

i have question. Is it possible to keep changes feed alive when hybrid app is in background or closed?

```
 var changes = db.changes({
    since: 'now',
    live: true,
    include_docs: true,
    timeout: false

    // attachments: true
  }).on('change', function (change) {

    onChange(change);

    // handle change
  }).on('complete', function (info) {
    // changes() was canceled
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The only way this could work is with Service Worker and Background Sync. It seems there's a polyfill for iOS: https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-service-worker-background-sync

Comment: Thanks nlawson,  i'll give it a try.